# Automatic email with HTML formatting

Tags: html, css, email

I've been trying to figure out if its possible for me to set an automatic reply that sends out an HTML formatted email. I need this to send out a fancy looking "We'll get back to you shortly" with images and links. I have the HTML code with me (with all headers and inline CSS), but I have no way to format the body of the email response as HTML.

Any ideas on how I can get this done?

I'm using Outlook Web App.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library like swiftmailer http://swiftmailer.org/

Comment: Thanks Adrian, but I doubt this will solve my problem. Its ridiculously simple to add a rich text automatic response but my problem is that I need my own custom HTML to go out as an automatic reply. I'm looking for a way to do this within the outlook client.

Answer (score 0):

Open up your text editor and get ready to start using tables. You're going to want to start out with something like this.

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
   <tr>
      <td>
         <table width="650" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tr>
             <!-- the amount of td you need -->
            </tr>
         </table>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Of course you'll need to figure out the exact layout, but expect to do a lot of table nesting. There are also issues between different email clients concerning how it all renders. Make sure if you're making an empty table cell used for spacing, make sure to do something like this.

```
<td style="height: 10px; font-size: 0; line-height: 0;">&nsbp;</td>
```

Otherwise you'll get unexpected spaces in things like Outlook. 
Campaign monitor has a lot of useful tips about building out emails, check it out [here](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/).